# How can i avoid writing the conditional statement twice for this jquery code?

Tags: jquery

i have a piece of jquery code that first checks device size when loading and for every subsequent windows resize it will put in the correct image. I found myself having to write the conditional statement twice. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
var wi=$(window).width();
//upon loading for first time, show correct image size
if (wi <=420)
{
$("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/main_image_xs.jpg")
 } 
else
{
   $("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/main_image_default.jpg")     
}
}

$(window).resize(function() {
// When resizing windows, show corect image size
if (wi <=420)
{
 $("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/main_image_xs.jpg")
 } 
 else
 {
   $("#main").find("img").attr("src","images/main_image_default.jpg")     
 }
 }
 });
 });
```

Comment: You can push that into a common function and call that method. By the way, the window ready is a strange event, never seen it in use. Use window `load()`. Also you haven't calculated the new window size on `resize()`

Comment: @Shaunak: Unless you know you need `load`, you usually want `ready`. `ready` will be fired once all of the page’s HTML has loaded and the DOM is complete; `load` waits until after all images, stylesheets, etc. have loaded as well, which could be significantly longer.

Comment: I know. But I have never seen a ready() event attached to window. It is usually related to the `document`. There seems no connection of DOM and the window.

Answer (score 2):

Use a named function, not an anonymous function.

```
function adjustImageSize() {
    var imageURL;
    if($(window).width() <= 420) {
        imageURL = "images/main_image_xs.jpg";
    }else{
        imageURL = "images/main_image_default.jpg";
    }
    $("#main img").attr("src", imageURL);
}

$(window).ready(adjustImageSize).resize(adjustImageSize);
```

Better yet, see if you can use media queries—then your website can adapt without needing JavaScript.